# How to exclude building files in Developer Studio?

Tags: eclipse, build, progress-4gl, openedge

How do you set up the project in Progress Developer Studio 3.7 (Eclipse 3.7.1) to ignore building specific files and/or folders?

```
src/main
src/main/somename.p
src/fix
```

I want to ignore building the file src/main/somename.p and the whole folder src/fix.
Preferably an easy way to change what files to build and not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's located under Project -> Properties -> Progress OpenEdge -> Build -> @{ROOT} Source (expand)

Double click (or click and Edit) on Excluded.

[image: Dialogue]

Answer (score 1):

You can select "Progress OpenEdge -> Exclude from build" in the pop-up menu on the source/directory you want to exclude.